# Ver espaço disponível no disco em PHP num servidor web

Tags: php

Eu tentei buscar o espaço disponível no disco mas ele obtém um número exuberante (124GB transformados) enquanto ele só tem 12GB livres. Eis o que usei.

```
<?php 
    $bytes = disk_free_space("."); 
    $si_prefix = array( 'B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB' );
    $base = 1024;
    $class = min((int)log($bytes , $base) , count($si_prefix) - 1);
    echo $bytes . '<br />';
    echo sprintf('%1.2f' , $bytes / pow($base,$class)) . ' ' . $si_prefix[$class] . '<br />';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente criar uma função para transformar o valor de bytes que retorna pelo [disk_free_space](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php) e exibir em tela.

Ficaria assim:

```
<?php 
function formatBytes($bytes, $precision = 2) 
{ 
    $base = log($bytes, 1024);
    $suffixes = array('', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T');   

    return round(pow(1024, $base - floor($base)), $precision) .' '. $suffixes[floor($base)];
}

$bytes = disk_free_space("."); 
echo formatBytes($bytes,2);

?>
```

Fonte:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510434/format-bytes-to-kilobytes-megabytes-gigabytes?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Irei tentar isso, informarei dentro em breve

Comment: Continua a dizer 124GB

Comment: Dê um echo na função disk_free_space e nos informe quantos bytes ele retorna